# OnMouseOver not activating function defined in head

Tags: javascript, html, function

I need to make my page show certain text when the user hovers over a certain image, and the text is different from each image. This is the code for the head:

```html
<head>
  <title>Indian Spices Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\CSS\cookingStyles.css">
  <script>
    function displayChilli() {
      document.getElementById("chilli").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("cumin").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cinnamon").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cloves").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("fenugreek").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cardamom").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("mustard").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("nutmeg").style.display = "none";
    }

    function displayCumin() {
      document.getElementById("chilli").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cumin").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("cinnamon").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cloves").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("fenugreek").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cardamom").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("mustard").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("nutmeg").style.display = "none";
    }

    function displayCinnamon() {
      document.getElementById("chilli").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cumin").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cinnamon").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("cloves").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("fenugreek").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cardamom").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("mustard").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("nutmeg").style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

This is the code for where the functions are meant to activate:

```html
<div>
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/chilliPowder.jpg" onMouseOver="displayChilli()">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/cumin.jpg" onMouseOver="displayCumin()">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/cinnamon.jpg" onMouseOver="displayCinnamon()">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/cloves.jpg">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/fenugreek.jpg">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/cardamom.jpg">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/mustardSeeds.jpg">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/nutmeg.jpg">
</div>
<section id="chlli" style="display:block">
  <h2>Chili Powder</h2>
  <p>
    <b>History</b>
    <br> Chili peppers originated in Mexico. Following the Columbian Exchange, many cultivars of chili pepper spread across the world.
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Uses</b>
    <br> Chili peppers are widely used in many cuisines to add spiciness to dishes. The substances that give chili peppers their intensity when ingested or applied topically are capsaicin and related compounds known as capsaicinoids.
  </p>
</section>

<section id="cumin" style="display:none">
  <h2>Cumin</h2>
  <p>
    <b>History</b>
    <br> Thought to originate around the Eastern Mediterranean, cumin has been in use as a spice for thousands of years with seeds excavated at archaeological sites dated to the second millennium BC.
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Uses</b>
    <br> Cumin can be used ground or as whole seeds. It has an earthy, warming and aromatic character making it a staple in stews, soups and spiced gravies such as curry and chili. It is also used as an ingredient in some pickles.
  </p>
</section>

<section id="cinnamon" style="display:none">
  <h2>Cinnamon</h2>
  <p>
    <b>History</b>
    <br> Cinnamon was imported to Egypt as early as 2000 BC. It was so highly prized among ancient nations that it was regarded as a gift fit for monarchs. Although its source was kept a closely guarded secret in the Mediterranean world for centuries,
    by those in the spice trade to protect their monopoly as suppliers, cinnamon is native to India, Sri Lanka, Bangladesh, and Myanmar.
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Uses</b>
    <br> Cinnamon is used mainly as an aromatic condiment and flavouring additive in a wide variety of cuisines, sweet and savoury dishes.
  </p>
</section>
```

I'm working  from an example in front of me that is structurally no different to my code. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem was that I misspelled "chilli". Fixing my spelling fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head>
  <title>Indian Spices Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\CSS\cookingStyles.css">
  
</head>

<div>
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/chilliPowder.jpg" onMouseOver="displayChilli()">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/cumin.jpg" onMouseOver="displayCumin()">
  <img class="Spices" src="../Images/cinnamon.jpg" onMouseOver="displayCinnamon()">
</div>
<section id="chilli" style="display:none">
  <h2>Chili Powder</h2>
  <p>
    <b>History</b>
    <br> Chili peppers originated in Mexico. Following the Columbian Exchange, many cultivars of chili pepper spread across the world.
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Uses</b>
    <br> Chili peppers are widely used in many cuisines to add spiciness to dishes. The substances that give chili peppers their intensity when ingested or applied topically are capsaicin and related compounds known as capsaicinoids.
  </p>
</section>

<section id="cumin" style="display:none">
  <h2>Cumin</h2>
  <p>
    <b>History</b>
    <br> Thought to originate around the Eastern Mediterranean, cumin has been in use as a spice for thousands of years with seeds excavated at archaeological sites dated to the second millennium BC.
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Uses</b>
    <br> Cumin can be used ground or as whole seeds. It has an earthy, warming and aromatic character making it a staple in stews, soups and spiced gravies such as curry and chili. It is also used as an ingredient in some pickles.
  </p>
</section>

<section id="cinnamon" style="display:none">
  <h2>Cinnamon</h2>
  <p>
    <b>History</b>
    <br> Cinnamon was imported to Egypt as early as 2000 BC. It was so highly prized among ancient nations that it was regarded as a gift fit for monarchs. Although its source was kept a closely guarded secret in the Mediterranean world for centuries,
    by those in the spice trade to protect their monopoly as suppliers, cinnamon is native to India, Sri Lanka, Bangladesh, and Myanmar.
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Uses</b>
    <br> Cinnamon is used mainly as an aromatic condiment and flavouring additive in a wide variety of cuisines, sweet and savoury dishes.
  </p>
</section>

<script>
    function displayChilli() {
      document.getElementById("chilli").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("cumin").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cinnamon").style.display = "none";
     
    }

    function displayCumin() {
      document.getElementById("chilli").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cumin").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("cinnamon").style.display = "none";
     
    }

    function displayCinnamon() {
      document.getElementById("chilli").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cumin").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cinnamon").style.display = "block";
     
    }
  </script>
```

As elements are not rendered when JavaScript compiled, it's not able to bind elements written in functions. So `Add` or `Load` script after body, just above `</body>` 
Typo in spelling of `chilli`

Comment: I've moved it, but there doesn't seem to make a difference. is there something i need to add in the <script> tag? I'm sorry if this seems really obvious to you, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Check the code I have added and modify according to your need. You also have typo `chilli`. Mark as answer if it answers your question

Comment: it turns out i misspelled "chilli". It's working perfectly fine now.